# How can I create an infinite scale mouseover animation with a smooth mouseout effect with css?

Tags: css, scale

I'm coding a CSS3 effect fired on mouseover; this effect simply animate an inner div scaling it endlessly.

All works great, but when I move the mouse away the div suddenly return to its original size. I would like to add a smooth effect to scale the div back.

I already checked the suggestion of this post:
[Make CSS Hover state remain after "unhovering"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering)
Unfortunately the code posted doesn't work :(
In my opinion my issue could be related with the "infinite" loop of the scale effect.

THe goal I would like to gain is the on mouse-out the image could return to its original size smoothly.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/9dtqpsLa/1/

**CSS**

```
@keyframes imageZoom{
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(1.24); }
    100% { transform: scale(1);}
}

@-moz-keyframes imageZoom{
    0% { -moz-transform: scale(1);}
    50% { -moz-transform: scale(1.24); }
    100% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageZoom{
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    50% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.24); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageZoom{
    0% { -ms-transform: scale(1); }
    50% { -ms-transform: scale(1.24); }
    100% { -ms-transform: scale(1); }
}

.article:hover .imageWrapper {
    animation: imageZoom linear 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation: imageZoom linear 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation: imageZoom linear 10s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation: imageZoom linear 10s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform-origin: 50% 80%;
}

.article {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.imageWrapper {
    background-image: url('http://www.astutegraphics.com/images/blog/tutorials/widthscribe_patterns_18_mar_2013/floral-seamless-pattern.png');
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="imageWrapper">

    </div>
</div>
```

Please, could you help me?

Thanks so much

Comment: This is happening because your animation is set to play on hover of `.article`. If you just want to *start* the animation on hover and then have it go on in perpetuity, you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make CSS Hover state remain after "unhovering"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090582/can-i-use-hover-to-trigger-a-css3-animation-or-transition-which-keeps-running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOALS:
1. Have the image animate expansion and contraction on hover
2. Have the image animate to original state on mouseleave

PROBLEMS:
With CSS, I don't know how to use both an `animation` and a `transition`. The `animation` is the pulsing on hover. The `transition` is the return to default animation. The only way I could envision doing it is with JS. See each section for notes

https://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/9dtqpsLa/5/

HTML:
notes: same as example provided

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="imageWrapper"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:
notes:
1. `animation` removed.
2. The `scale` is only fired with the existence of `[data-dir='expand']`.
3. `transform-origin` and `transition` moved into the default state of `.imageWrapper`
4. need to add prefixes

```
.article[data-dir='expand'] .imageWrapper {
    transform:scale(1.24)
}

.article {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.imageWrapper {
    background-image: url('http://www.astutegraphics.com/images/blog/tutorials/widthscribe_patterns_18_mar_2013/floral-seamless-pattern.png');
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform-origin: 50% 80%;
    transition:all 10.0s linear 0.0s;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:
notes:
1. all new

```
/*
     1. on hover aka 'mouseenter' start the animation
     2. 10 seconds in, change direction of the animation based on the `isHovering` variable
     3. on exit aka 'mouseleave', return to default
 */


var thisArticle = document.querySelector('.article'),
    thisTimer = '',
    isHovering = false;

thisArticle.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    console.log('mouseenter');
    thisArticle.setAttribute('data-dir', 'expand');
    thisTimer = setInterval(fireAnimation, 10000);
    isHovering = true
}, false);

thisArticle.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log('mouseleave');
    thisArticle.removeAttribute('data-dir');
    isHovering = false;
    clearInterval(thisTimer);
}, false);

var fireAnimation = function(){
    if(isHovering){
        if(thisArticle.getAttribute('data-dir') === 'expand'){
            thisArticle.removeAttribute('data-dir');
        } else {
            thisArticle.setAttribute('data-dir', 'expand');
        }
    } else {
        clearInterval(thisTimer);
    }
    alert('change direction');
}
```

**MORE IDEAS**
1. I used a `data` attribute, but I would prefer to use `classList`. Wasn't sure how to incorporate that into the fiddle in 30 seconds, so skipped it.
2. The return to default animation has no awareness of the `scale` when you leave, so it takes 10 seconds no matter what. I'm sure there is a way to make this better.

Comment: And the future is bright. This would be even better with http://web-animations.github.io/ because it's easier to figure out where the animation is.

Comment: Great!! It seems to works properly! I'm check it into my website :) Thanks so much

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `console.log`s!

Comment: One more infos; I've mani article alements, how can I edit your code to fire the scale in and scale out on each element? Thanks so Much

Answer (score 0):

Once you the mouse is moved away from the element, the styles in the :hover pseudo class gets removed from your element, effectively putting it back where it started.

What you want to do is start and pause the animation:

Here is your fiddle, I edited it a bit and exploded the short-hand and removed -webkit, -ms, etc:

https://jsfiddle.net/9dtqpsLa/4/

```
@keyframes imageZoom {
    100% {
        transform: scale(4);
    }
}
.article:hover .imageWrapper {
    animation-play-state: running;
}
.article {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.imageWrapper {
    background-image: url('http://www.astutegraphics.com/images/blog/tutorials/widthscribe_patterns_18_mar_2013/floral-seamless-pattern.png');
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform-origin: 50% 80%;
    animation-name: imageZoom;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: both;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Notice that all the animation logic has moved to the base class, and the :hover only kicks off the animation.

Comment: Thanks :) but I would like that on mouseout the image will return to its natural size... Thanks so much